# How spark dataframe optimization engine works with DAG?

Tags: apache-spark, query-optimization, rdd, apache-spark-sql

Lets say, we have

```
val df = bigTableA.join(bigTableB,bigTableA("A")===bigTableB("A"),"left")
val rddFromDF = df.rdd
println(rddFromDF.count)
```

My understanding is that spark will convert all data frame operations before "rddFromDF.count" into RDD equivalent operation as we are not performing any action on dataframe directly. In that case, spark will not be using optimization engine. Is my assumption right? Please point me to right resources.